# RHEL 7 Still CPU Frequency Scaling

Tags: rhel, performance, cpu-frequency

When machine is imaged with:

RHEL6.x

- CPU speeds report full 3.3Ghz speed for all CPUs
- cpupowerutils is not installed

RHEL7.x

- CPU speeds vary (shown in example below)
- cpupowerutils is installed

I have checked the following:

- `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` in RHEL7.x. It indicates `performance` for all CPUs.
- To see if kondemand is running using `pgrep -lf kondemand`. It is not
- To see if cpuspeed service is running using `service cpuspeed status`. It is not-found

Example RHEL 7.x cpu frequencies:

```
grep -E '^cpu MHz' /proc/cpuinfo
cpu MHz         : 3317.273
cpu MHz         : 2028.210
cpu MHz         : 3464.226
cpu MHz         : 3237.480
cpu MHz         : 3455.332
cpu MHz         : 1913.484
cpu MHz         : 3425.167
cpu MHz         : 2592.304
cpu MHz         : 2746.218
cpu MHz         : 2739.128
cpu MHz         : 3202.417
cpu MHz         : 3368.191
cpu MHz         : 2815.441
cpu MHz         : 3165.292
cpu MHz         : 3327.457
cpu MHz         : 2539.066
```

Output of cpupower:

```
cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  driver: intel_pstate
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: 0
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: 0
  maximum transition latency: 0.97 ms.
  hardware limits: 1.20 GHz - 3.50 GHz
  available cpufreq governors: performance, powersave
  current policy: frequency should be within 1.20 GHz and 3.50 GHz.
                  The governor "performance" may decide which speed to use
                  within this range.
  current CPU frequency is 1.59 GHz (asserted by call to hardware).
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
    3400 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
    3400 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
    3500 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
    3500 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

Comment: cpu MHz could [lie to you](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9773775/)

Answer (score 1):

RHEL7 introduced a new daemon called 'tuned' which touches a bunch of settings including the cpu scaling. Check to see if that's running and mucking with things

Comment: do  a `tuned-adm profile latency-performance`

Answer (score 0):

I like doing

```
sudo watch -n 1  cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

in a terminal window to see cpu speed.

Using `tuned` you change change the power profiles real time

```
tuned-adm  active

tuned-adm  list

# to set the current profile do the following

tuned-adm profile  <choice from the list>
```

Observe the real time change of core frequencies from that watch command.

Also, `yum install tuned*` and `yum install tuna`